# How to get the last array display in entity symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I don't know if this is possible in symfony, that is getting the last array when using respository. In my controller a have this function

```
/**
 * @param $id
 * @return Food
 */
public function getFood($id)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $food = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Food")->findById($id);
    if (!$food) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException("Invalid Food");
    }

    return $food;
}
```

this will show the single food that I need.  In my repository I have this code

```
/**
     * Display Food and get the last transaction
     * @param $id
     */
    public function findById($id){

        $query =  $this->createQueryBuilder(f)
            ->where('f.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()[0];

        return $query;
    }
```

This code successfully displaying the data of food
Foods

```
 - id
 - name
 - price
 - packages
     - id
     - name_package
     - category
 - User
     - id
     - username
     - password
     - email
- transaction []
    1 - {
         - id
         - date
         - emailStatus
         - email
     }
    2 - {
         - id
         - date
         - emailStatus
         - email
     }
    3 - {
         - id
         - date
         - emailStatus
         - email
     }
```

How can I get the last transaction of food? I just want to display the last part of transaction that is like this one.

**update**

```
     - id
     - name
     - price
     - packages
         - id
         - name_package
         - category
     - User
         - id
         - username
         - password
         - email
    - transaction []
         3 - {
             - id
             - date
             - emailStatus
             - email
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone here. I have an idea now how to solve. What I did is just a  simple way. In my Food entity class, I add this method

```
/**
     * @return Transactions
     */
    public function getLastTransactions()
    {
        $this->transactions = $this->getTransactions()->last();

        return $this->transactions;
    }
```

and then in my Food controller

```
 /**
     * @param $id
     * @return Food
     */
    public function getFood($id)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $food = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Food")->find($id);
        $food->getLastTransactions();


        return $food;
    }
```

I can now control the transaction and then you can see the full info of my food entity.

Answer (score 1):

You could slice your transaction array and retrieve a new one with only the last item in it. Then you can reset the indices for the array and fetch the only item with the index 0.

```
$transaction = array_values(array_slice($food, -1))[0];
```

Comment: sorry if I made u confuse. I update my post. The update part is the one that I need to display. I'm using the last() function, as what other use. but I want to be optional. There is also a scenario that I need all transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `transation` field (containing transactions) in `Food` is an [`ArrayCollection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html)

If so, there's a method `last()` which returns last element from the collection.

So you can do something like this, if you have getter for transactions:

```
$food->getTransaction()->last();
```

Comment: I used this one, but there is also a scenario that I need all transaction

Comment: Is there anything that will stop you from getting all transaction?

Comment: It is fine for me if I get all transaction, my code work for that. but there is also a scenario that I need only the last transaction. I used this last() but it also affect the other one of my code.

Comment: That's another issue. Provide code for that, so we can see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can add method to Food class

```
/**
 * @return Transaction|null
 */
public function getLastTransaction()
{
    $transactions = $this->getTransaction();

    return !empty($transactions) ? end($transactions) : null;
}
```

Comment: I'm also working like fetching the last transaction. the last() is working fine if I want the last transaction but there is also a scenario that I need all transaction.

Comment: Am I going to add this in my Food entity?

Comment: Yes. Then if you want last transaction then call `$food->getLastTransaction()`, if you need all then call `$food->getTransaction()`

Comment: sorry I made u confuse. I update my post. the update is the one that I need to display. You're right if only want is the transaction, but I also need the info of food

Comment: Of course. Just return your `Food` object in place where you need to show it. And then call any method you need. `$food->getPrice()`, `$food->getLastTransaction()->getDate()`...

Comment: with this approach you could simply use `last()` / `first()` since the just wrappers for `end()` and `reset()`, but there could be gotchas, see my answer why

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get what you need.

**First**, update your `findById()` method. Since you look for Id, I assume you'd like to get only one record, right ?

```
/**
     * Display Food and get the last transaction
     * @param $id
     * @return Food|null
     */

public function findById($id){

  $query =  $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
            ->where('f.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();     
            // returns single Object instead of an array of Objects 

  return $query;
}
```

then navigate to your `Food` entity an extend your relation to transaction => add `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` This is a important Part for later "filtering"

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="...", mappedBy="...", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
*/
private $transaction;
```

then stay in your `Food` entity add additional method(s) for transaction depending on your current usecase(s).

for example:

that would be your regular transactions getter which gives you all transaction for current `Food` as ArrayCollection

```
public function getTransaction()
{
  return $this->transaction;
}
```

so the easy way would be to use `first()/last()` methods

like

```
public function getOnlyLastTransaction()
{
  return $this->transaction->last();
}
```

now you have two (or even more) separate method(s) for a different task(s)

but... `first()` and `last()` are handy wrappers for php's native `reset()` and `end()` functions, so if your `Food` have say 100 transaction, doctine will fetch all from DB and hydrate to `Transaction` entity just only to get first. Not the best way.

at **this point** you can make use of [Doctrine's Criteria](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)

so now you can update your `getOnlyLastTransaction()` method with following

```
/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getOnlyLastTransaction ()
{
    // here you filter your transactions at SQL level
    // so you could sa, get all transaction of current food ordered by ID in desc order and get only ONE of them by LIMIT 1
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->orderBy( [ 'id' => Criteria::DESC ] ); // id of transaction Entity
    // $criteria->orderBy(['date' => Criteria::DESC ]); // to get last by date
    $criteria->setMaxResults( 1 ); // LIMIT 1

    return $this->transaction->matching( $criteria );
}
```

the best part of it -> you get still ArrayCollection back so all methods like `first()`, `last()` and `isEmpty()` are still available, the only difference is **you have a collection of one**

so my fav is to extend method with param `$as_object` like

```
public function getOnlyLastTransaction ( $as_object = TRUE )
{
    // here you filter your transactions at SQL level
    // so you could sa, get all transaction of current food ordered by ID in desc order and get only ONE of them by LIMIT 1
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->orderBy( [ 'id' => Criteria::DESC ] ); // id of transaction Entity
    // $criteria->orderBy(['date' => Criteria::DESC ]); // to get last by date
    $criteria->setMaxResults( 1 ); // LIMIT 1
    $found = $this->transaction->matching( $criteria );
    return ($as_object ? $found->first() : $found);
}
```

Now you have full controll and **only one transaction** in a separate method, so if you still want all of then, you can use your regular getter

**usage:** in your controller

/**
 * @param $id
 * @return Food
 */
public function getFood($id)
{

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$food = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Food")->findById($id);
if (fasle === $food instanceof Food ) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException("Invalid Food");
}
$lastTrans = $food->getOnlyLastTransaction();
dump($lastTrans);


return $food;
```

}

**GOTCHAS**

`last()` and `first()` could lead to a confusing if someone changed default sorting of your relation via `@ORM\OrderBy({...})`
For Example. If your relation looks like this

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="...", mappedBy="...", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"date"="DESC"})
 */
private $transaction;
```

So now when you call

`$food->getTransaction()->last()` and awaiting the last record, you get **the last entry of colllection** which in this case actualy the **first record from DB**

Comment: I try to add getOnlyFirstTransaction() in my food entity and now here's my controller code  " $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $food = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Food")->find($id);".

Comment: The result is still the same I get all the transaction. Did I miss something about the code?

Comment: First of all, sorry for confusing methods name. It should be `getOnlyLastTransaction` since you want the last one and you oder by DESC.
As i said `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` is important
```php
$food = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Food")->find($id);
$lastTrans = $food->getOnlyLastTransaction( $as_object = true );
dump($lastTrans);
```

Comment: Yes this is the same as other answer. It get the last transaction. That is correct but not only the last transaction that I need to display and also the user, prices and so on. the update part of my post. is the one that need to display in my page. thanks for your answer.

Comment: if it's only matter of displaying then use  `getOnlyLastTransaction` in twig and you're goot to go ;)

```php
{%if food.getOnlyLastTransaction|default %}
{{ food.getOnlyLastTransaction.date|date('Y-m-d H:i') }}
{%endif %}
```

For this case no looping over all transaction required

Comment: I have problem when loading a page if I can't cut the code in getting all transaction.